# SSL_do_handshake() failed: SSL: error:10000089 and SSL: error:1e000065

Tags: nginx, ssl, google-cloud-platform, tls1.2

I have an nginx server on gcp as a reverse proxy terminating https for the backend application with TLS1.0/TLS1.1/TLS1.2 all enabled, and I keep getting this error on the Log explorer for the proxy:
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC) while SSL handshaking, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:443"

and also:
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC) while SSL handshaking, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: could you attach your `nginx.conf`, I'm curious about `ssl_*` directives

Comment: Is this error generated from just certain public traffic and works for other traffic? Scanners will look for TLS vulnerabilities. In that case, there is nothing you can do short of firewalling those scanners. I would add a Google Cloud load balancer in front of your system to prevent that traffic. Your question has zero details on the Nginx configuration or the traffic that generates those errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am also facing the same error under container log I found
 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14201044:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:internal error) while SSL handshaking, client: 71.6.135.131, server: 0.0.0.0:443